# Windows Mobile Classic 6 - Defragging?

Tags: defragment, windows-mobile-6

My Windows Mobile PDA is really sluggish lately, is it possible that it needs to be defragged?  Also, is there anyway to defrag a Windows Mobile device?

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/13668/what-does-a-defrag-actually-do

Comment: PDA questions are offtopic here unless regarding syncing to a computer.  try a phone/gadget StackExchange site [on this list](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/list-of-stackexchange-sites) -- [AskAboutGadgets](http://askaboutgadgets.com/) or possibly [PhoneHow](http://phonehow.com/) may be appropriate, or check the list for other possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defragging should not be a concern since the Windows Mobile device does not use a disk drive with moving parts.  Flash memory shouldn't be subject to the kinds of performance issues that exist with fragmented hard drives.  I would suggest backing up the device and reloading it after a hard reset.  (restoring data to most systems has the net effect of defragmenting it).

Answer (score 0):

Your device is probably running on flash storage, so defragmentation is not advised.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that fragmentation in hard disks causes poor performance is because it increases the amount of physical movement required to read data.

Flash memory (which your PDA uses, along with SSDs, USB thumbdrives, etc), does not have moving parts, hence fragmentation is not an issue.