# Windows 7 SSD optimizations applied when?

Tags: windows-7, backup, ssd, restore

I've got a Windows 7 install running on my laptop, and will be upgrading to an SSD shortly.  If I take a Windows system image backup from my current HD, and restore it to my SSD, will I get the SSD optimizations, or does Windows do those checks during the install?  If so, is there some way I can force Windows to recheck and/or act accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can apply the image on the new SSD.
Afterwards you can check what Windows think of the drive. Run this from a cmd window...

```
fsutil behavior query disabledeletenotify
```

If DisableDeleteNotify = 0 then Windows recognize your SSD.

Here are some links/hints for SSD drives:

- [Optimize windows for solid state drives usage](http://www.ghacks.net/2009/01/10/optimize-windows-for-solid-state-drives-usage/)
- [MSDN blog about SSD](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx)
- [SSD Windows Registry Tweaks](http://www.ocztechnologyforum.com/forum/showthread.php?t=47244)
- [Intel SSD Toolbox](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9139917/Intel_releases_Windows_7_SSD_optimization_toolbox)

Comment: Not quite correct. DisableDeleteNotify should equal 0, if TRIM is enabled by Windows. This should be beneficial if the SSD supports TRIM. See: http://superuser.com/questions/74896/confirming-that-windows-7-is-using-ssd-optimizations/76210#76210