# Does Windows 7 see my SSD as HDD?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd

i installed Win7 on an SSD (intel X25-M G2) and i guess it does not recognize it as an SSD since some services are still running that should be disabled automatically (like superfetch).
I enabled AHCI-Mode in the Bios.
Does someone know how to check if it uses the drive as an SSD?

Thanks.

Comment: May be of some use: http://superuser.com/questions/74896/confirming-that-windows-7-is-using-ssd-optimizations

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The windows team have said this:

> **Will Superfetch be disabled on SSDs?**
>
> Yes, for most systems with SSDs.
>
> If the system disk is an SSD, and the
>   SSD performs adequately on random
>   reads and doesn’t have glaring
>   performance issues with random writes
>   or flushes, then Superfetch, boot
>   prefetching, application launch
>   prefetching, ReadyBoost and ReadDrive
>   will all be disabled.
>
> Initially, we had configured all of
>   these features to be off on all SSDs,
>   but we encountered sizable performance
>   regressions on some systems. In root
>   causing those regressions, we found
>   that some first generation SSDs had
>   severe enough random write and flush
>   problems that ultimately lead to disk
>   reads being blocked for long periods
>   of time. With Superfetch and other
>   prefetching re-enabled, performance on
>   key scenarios was markedly improved.

Source: [Engineering Windows 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/e7/archive/2009/05/05/support-and-q-a-for-solid-state-drives-and.aspx)

So it seems that disabling Superfetch isn't a guaranteed way to check things. I'd guess that it's working fine, as long as the correct drivers are being used.