# Howto manually force Windows 7 to work in the way as it had SSD vs hard drive

Tags: windows, ssd, performance, virtualbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confirming that Windows 7 is using SSD optimizations](https://superuser.com/questions/74896/confirming-that-windows-7-is-using-ssd-optimizations)

I have a SSD and Windows 7 working in virtual environment (VirtualBox).

Windows 7 works great with SSD but I wonder may be it "thinks" it has hard drive and not SSD?
I manually disabled some services like deframentation, superfetch etc.

I just want to know is it possible to make Windows 7 working with hard drive in SSD mode?

Comment: I would gunk the preferable solution would be to make your virtualization software emulate SSD. The being said, I don't see any benefit to you either way. The virtualization soware is going to treat that file (your virtual hdd) how it sees fit, so if you are concerned about your SDD life, I would be more concerned with the hypervisor than the guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows will set up SSD mode when WINSAT scores for HDD be higher than a specific value. If you want to use your Windows without defrag and superfetch with HDD it will works, but you will have a loss of performace over time.

Comment: Any reference to back this up with? This feels like speculation and there are way more correct ways to identify whether a hard drive is a SSD or HDD.

Comment: I read it once, i will find and post my reference.

Comment: "In Windows 7, SuperFetch is automatically enabled for disks that have a low Windows 
Experience Disk Score and disabled for disks that have a high score. "  http://www.windows7update.com/support-files/win7perf.pdf